# PDFKit Swift control zoom

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I want to control the zoom level of pdf file. By default when it launches it doesn't fits the screen. Even manually (pinch zoom) zoom-in and zoom-out doesn't make it fit the page. I have set the autoScales for true.

Also tried playing with below variable but it didn't help

```
   open var scaleFactorForSizeToFit: CGFloat { get }
```

Below is my code for the same

```
    pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.bounds)
    pdfdocument = PDFDocument(url: filePathUrl!)
    pdfView.document = pdfdocument
    pdfView.displayMode = PDFDisplayMode.singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

[image: Control]

Some control were user can control zoom level.

Can it be achieved using gesture recognizer?

Any Hint in right direction would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use scaleFactor to adjust zooming using UISlider.

```
pdfView.scaleFactor = 0.5
```